# Identifying Firebase Storage upload by a user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have implemented `Firebase Storage`, in which users can upload some images to `Firebase Storage`. I don't want to implement a user authentication functionality in my `Android` application.

But I want to group together the images uploaded by a particular user. I mean without a username, I want to identify that these images were uploaded by a particular user or device.

So how can I group together the files with some kind of identifier from the phone, so that I can classify it later. Is there some kind of unique identifier for each of the `Firebase` user or some identifier which I can put as metadata from images that I upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement Firebase Authentication `Anonymous auth`, which according to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth)

> Use Firebase features that require authentication without requiring users to sign in first by creating temporary anonymous accounts. If the user later chooses to sign up, you can upgrade the anonymous account to a regular account, so the user can continue where they left off.

This should give you a unique upload `User UID` for each anonymous account, see the furthest right column of the below picture "User Auth".

**Edit:**

Looks like I missed the second half of your question.

You could create an image_upload JSON structure in your "Database", then link the `User UID` to the `Storage Location` upload url. See the below example I made titled **Database User**.

**User Auth**
[image]

**Database User**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An idea it could be that on the client side when you send the image to firebase, you could set it a prefix with his id in the Beginning of the image file. And if you want to return them take him out those characters.

That way, on the server side if you want to look for an specific user image you just have to filter by those first characters in the list of files stored and make what you want with them :)